# how to access values of controls from userControl on another page in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

DocumentControl is my usercontrol, and I have written following lines in my function, but I am getting the value as blank.

```
var DocumentControl1 = new DocumentControl();                        
string docCode= DocumentControl1.txtDocCode.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of txtDocCode in a public variable as docCode. you can access the value like this,

```
DocumentControl1  d= new DocumentControl();
string docCode = d.DocCode;
```